# adding using file integers input

Tags: c, file, input

so i got the whole setup for my program and i was able to read the whole file content. the only one thing i need is to be able to add each column and put it in the variables i made. first column is miles second is gallons. so how can i make it possible using my code.

54 250 19

62 525 38

71 123 6

85 1322 86

97 235 14

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    // pointer file
    FILE *pFile;
    char line[128];
    int miles;
    int gallons;
    int mpg;

    // opening name of file with mode
    pFile = fopen("Carpgm.txt","r");

    //headers
    printf("Car No.  Miles Driven    Gallons Used\n");
    //checking if file is real and got right path
    if (pFile != NULL)
    {

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pFile) != NULL)
        {
            int a, b, c;

            if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
            {
                /* Values read */
                printf("%d        %d             %d\n",a, b, c);


            }


        }
        mpg = miles / gallons;
        printf("Total miles driven: \n",miles);
        printf("Total Gallons of gas: \n",gallons);
        printf("Average MPG: \n",mpg);

        printf("%d",a);

        //closing file
        fclose(pFile);        
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");     

    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not see your problem. You want to add up which values and put it where? Btw., you mention only two columns, but I see three, so maybe you forgot one column (car no.?).

Comment: i want to add the second column number together and the third same way but i cant get each number alone.

Comment: in other words how can i grab each number alone

Comment: so if i want to add 250 + 525 to 235, how can i do that

Comment: So you want to sum up each the second column and the third column?

Answer (score 1):

That depends what you want to do.

If you just want to add values, you can do something like:

```
    ...
    int miles = 0;
    int gallons = 0;
    ...
    /* Values read */
    miles += b;
    gallons += c;
    ...
```

Note that you can't print `a` like you did before closing the file as `a` is defined only in the `while` loop.
Furthermore, your printf statements won't work as expected, you forgot to specify the format `%d`, do:

```
    printf("Total miles driven: %d\n",miles);
    printf("Total Gallons of gas: %d\n",gallons);
    printf("Average MPG: %d\n",mpg);
```

Comment: If this is the response to your question you can accept it.